# How to get the country name from the card.io SDK ? - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, card.io

[Card.io](https://www.card.io/) [SDK](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK) provides the following details :

Card number, expiryMonth, year, CVV and Postal code.

How to get the country name from this SDK.

```
- (void)userDidProvideCreditCardInfo:(CardIOCreditCardInfo *)info inPaymentViewController:(CardIOPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController {
    NSLog(@"Scan succeeded with info: %@", info);
}
```

Is there any way to get country name from this SDK?

Please note that I am using Objective-C.

Comment: Well how about postal code? I know postal codes are sometimes used multiple time (for different countries) but you could check the postal code and then compare it to the time zone. Maybe that would work.

Comment: @LinusG. Ok, I will try.

Comment: @LinusG. postal code always comes null

Comment: Hm. Sorry, I cannot help you. I do not know card.io at all. That was just a random idea.

Comment: @LinusG. Ok, No Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave from card.io here.

No, the SDK does not ask the user to enter their country (and, of course, the country is not available from scanning the front of their credit card).

Re postal code: If when you create the `CardIOPaymentViewController` you set the `collectPostalCode` property to `YES`, then the user will be prompted to enter their postal code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood by your answer. #Dave